# Dynamic data with constant bar width in d3.js bar graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, overflow, bar-chart

I need to put a d3 bar graph on my website. The data there comes dynamically from server. Data can be very large or can be small too.
I have mentioned the code below.

*When the data increases dynamically*, how can I automatically add scroll-bar instead of reducing the width of bars?

Similarly if the data is less, the bar size should be constant.

```js
// Setup svg using Bostock's margin convention

var margin = {top: 20, right: 160, bottom: 35, left: 30};

var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


/* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */

var data = [
  { year: "2006", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "9", pears: "6" },
  { year: "2007", redDelicious: "12", mcintosh: "18", oranges: "9", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2008", redDelicious: "05", mcintosh: "20", oranges: "8", pears: "2" },
  { year: "2009", redDelicious: "01", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "5", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2010", redDelicious: "02", mcintosh: "10", oranges: "4", pears: "2" },
  { year: "2011", redDelicious: "03", mcintosh: "12", oranges: "6", pears: "3" },
  { year: "2012", redDelicious: "04", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "8", pears: "1" },
  { year: "2013", redDelicious: "06", mcintosh: "11", oranges: "9", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2014", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "13", oranges: "9", pears: "5" },
  { year: "2015", redDelicious: "16", mcintosh: "19", oranges: "6", pears: "9" },
  { year: "2016", redDelicious: "19", mcintosh: "17", oranges: "5", pears: "7" },
  { year: "2017", redDelicious: "04", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "8", pears: "1" },
  { year: "2018", redDelicious: "06", mcintosh: "11", oranges: "9", pears: "4" },
 
];

var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;


// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["redDelicious", "mcintosh", "oranges", "pears"].map(function(fruit) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {x: parse(d.year), y: +d[fruit]};
  });
}));


// Set x, y and colors
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
  .rangeRoundBands([10, width-10], 0.02);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {  return d3.max(d, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; });  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447", "#d9d574"];


// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5)
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat( function(d) { return d } );

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);


// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });


// Draw legend

var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")"; });
 
legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {return colors.slice().reverse()[i];});
 
legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 5)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d, i) { 
    switch (i) {
      case 0: return "Anjou pears";
      case 1: return "Naval oranges";
      case 2: return "McIntosh apples";
      case 3: return "Red Delicious apples";
    }
  });


// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
var tooltip = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");
    
tooltip.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);

tooltip.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

```css
 svg {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
  }
 
  path.domain {
    stroke: none;
  }
 
  .y .tick line {
    stroke: #ddd;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>d3.js learning</title>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a `div` with fixed `width` and `height` and let the div have a scroll along `x`. Append your chart `svg` inside the `div` and adjust the chart `width` according to length of your data.

Here's a fiddle. Try adding or removing data points in it.

```js
// Setup svg using Bostock's margin convention

var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 160,
  bottom: 35,
  left: 30
};

var width,height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var data = [
  { year: "2006", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "9", pears: "6" }
 
];

//Calculate width based on the number of data points and multiply by 60 to give sufficient width to the bars.
width = (data.length * 60) - margin.left - margin.right;

// If calculated width is lesser than the div container width, set a minimum width of 700px 
if (width < $('#chartContainer').width()) {
  width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right;
}

var svg = d3.select("#chartContainer")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


/* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */


var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;


// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["redDelicious", "mcintosh", "oranges", "pears"].map(function(fruit) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {
      x: parse(d.year),
      y: +d[fruit]
    };
  });
}));


// Set x, y and colors
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  }))
  .rangeRoundBands([10, width - 10], 0.8/data.length);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d, function(d) {
      return d.y0 + d.y;
    });
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447", "#d9d574"];


// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5)
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d
  });

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
//.selectAll('text');


// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors[i];
  });

var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.x);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.y0 + d.y);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y);
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    tooltip.style("display", null);
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    tooltip.style("display", "none");
  })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });


// Draw legend

var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")";
  });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors.slice().reverse()[i];
  });

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 5)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d, i) {
    switch (i) {
      case 0:
        return "Anjou pears";
      case 1:
        return "Naval oranges";
      case 2:
        return "McIntosh apples";
      case 3:
        return "Red Delicious apples";
    }
  });


// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
var tooltip = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");

tooltip.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);

tooltip.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

```css
svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}

path.domain {
  stroke: none;
}

.y .tick line {
  stroke: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>d3.js learning</title>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div id='chartContainer' style="overflow-x:scroll;max-width: 400px;height:330px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But the only problem now is that suppose we have only one data point. then the width of bar chart is again too large.

Comment: @Madhuri Please check the updated fiddle now. What I changed is that now the padding between the bars is also according to the number or data points. 
I've kept only one data point for now. You can add more data points and try it.

Comment: It is just awesome..Thanks so much.. I always used to stuck here.. understood now!